# Gradle optional @Input

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-task

How can I provide an optional property for task?

```
class CustomTask extends DefaultTask {

    @Input
    Closure preconfig

    // ...    
}
```

This way obligates user to provide `preconfig` closure as parameter when defining task with `CustomTask` type.

How can I achieve declarative way other than defining methods to set properties?

```
class CustomTask extends DefaultTask {

    @Input
    Closure preconfig

    def preconfig(Closure c){
        this.preconfig = c
    }

    // ...   
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, I found a solution in assigning default value to the `@Input` fields.

Example:

```
class CustomTask extends DefaultTask {

    @Input
    Closure preconfig = null // or { } <- empty closure

    // ...    
}
```

And then check if the `@Input` variable is not null:

```
// ...

@TaskAction
def action(){
    if (preconfig) { preconfig() }
}

// ...
```

Also there is useful annotation [`@Optional`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/Optional.html):

```
class CustomTask extends DefaultTask {

    @Input @Optional
    Closure preconfig

    // ...    
}
```

Comment: can I also use the `@Optional` in a build.gradle file? For example if I have something like:

        task npmBuild (type: Exec) {
            inputs.dir './src' ...

, can I make this optional?

Answer (score 2):

```
class CustomTask extends DefaultTask {
    void setPreconfig(Closure c) {
        inputs.property("preconfig", c)
    }
    ...
}
```

@see [TaskInputs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskInputs.html)

Comment: Well, in this way I also have to declare separate method